# Ng-select: Get previous value on clear

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to get the value of an ng-select field **before** it is cleared.

All change events seem to return only the new value at the moment.

```
<ng-select [items]="importerFields" [(ngModel)]="selectedConstant[constant.constant_name]" bindLabel="label"
                        [multiple]="constant.allow_match_with_multiple_constants"
                        [closeOnSelect]="!constant.allow_match_with_multiple_constants" appendTo="body"
                        placeholder="{{ ('IMPORTER.FILES_COLUMN' | translate).replace('CONSTANT_NAME', constant.label) }}"
                        (change)="constantChanged(constant, $event)">
                    </ng-select>
```

Using the above code example, when the X button is pressed to clear the ng-select's contents, the value returned from **$event** inside the function **constantChanged** returns **undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

Ng-Select always provides you with the currently selected value. So in this case you need to maintain previous value manually in a following way.

Your ts should look like this:

```
public previousValue: any;

constructor(): void {
  // set your previousValue to the current value of select
  // handle it in a constructor or when you load your data
}

public change($event: any): void {
  // here you can compare your previousValue with current one in $event

  // don't forget to set your previousValue to current one
  this.previousValue = $event;
}
```

Your template will be following:

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="model" [items]="items" (change)="change($event)"></ng-select>
```